# Cordova admob-plus keeps adding the wrong application id to android manifest

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, admob

I've installed the admob-plus plugin as per their documentation and all works fine on iOS, but when i come to build the ionc/cordova project it's adding the wrong application id to the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="ca-app-pub-xxx~yyy" />
```

This is not the application ID i have in package.json (substituted the numbers for 0s)

```
"admob-plus-cordova": {
        "APP_ID_ANDROID": "ca-app-pub-00000000000000~000000000",
        "PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION": "20.3.0",
        "APP_ID_IOS": "ca-app-pub-00000000000000~000000000",
        "USAGE": "This identifier will be used to deliver personalized ads to you.",
        "DISABLESDKCRASHREPORTING": "false"
      },
```

I have removed the platform: ionic cordova platform rm ios and added it again, and it keeps copying ca-app-pub-xxx~yyy into the manifest instead of the real id.

If i alter the manifest manually then run ionic cordova build android it now duplicates it in the manfiest, again with ca-app-pub-xxx~yyy

Answer (score 0):

Since I have the app already on github, deleting entirely the source code and cloning it again solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify app ids when you install :

cordova plugin add admob-plus-cordova --save --variable APP_ID_ANDROID=ca-app-pub-xxx --variable APP_ID_IOS=ca-app-pub-xxx